# Finding the logarithm of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, logarithms

Find $B$ if $A=e^B$ and 
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&0\\
0&2&0\\
0&0&4\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

Besides, I would be very happy if give some general remark(Best approach). I have seen the wiki article on log of a matrix but it was too complicated(for me).

Comment: Can you add any logic you have.

Comment: Is it $log A=B$ after taking logs

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: yes, isn't it?

Comment: So now its just taking log of a matrix where you can use net to see power series as i dont remember it for now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make use of the [block structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) of $A$:
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
C & 0 \\
0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
= e^B
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k} B^k
\Rightarrow
B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
D & 0 \\
0 & x
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so we can assume $4 = e^x \Rightarrow x = \ln(4)$.
For the block matrices we get
$$
C =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
=
e^D = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} D^k
$$
and try an upper triangular matrix
$$
D = 
\begin{pmatrix}
y & z \\
0 & y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and get the powers
$$
D^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
y & z \\
0 & y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y & z \\
0 & y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y^2 & 2 y z \\
0 & y^2
\end{pmatrix}
\\
D^3 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
y^2 & 2 y z \\
0 & y^2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
y & z \\
0 & y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
y^3 & 3 y^2 z \\
0 & y^3
\end{pmatrix}
\\
\vdots
\\
D^k =
\begin{pmatrix}
y^k & k y^{k-1} z \\
0 & y^k
\end{pmatrix}
\quad (k \ge 1)
$$
which suggest
$$
C =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
=
e^D 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
e^y & e^y z \\
0 & e^y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $y = \ln(2)$ and $z = 1/e^y = 1/2$.
This gives
$$
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
\ln(2) & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & \ln(2) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \ln(4)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: @ mvw , in fact there is a unique real solution. To prove that, you must prove the implication in line 2 and the fact that $D$ is necessarily upper-triangular.

Comment: I used without proof that diagonal matrices are closed under matrix addition, matrix multiplication and multiplication with a scalar. The same for upper triangular matrices. The powers of $D$ might be proofed by induction and the result for $C$ by comparing component-wise.  The given matrix is a lucky case where one can calculate the result like above.

Comment: Yes I agree. That I wanted to say is that $B,D$ are necessarily in the above form because $AB=BA$ and $CD=DC$.

Answer (score 1):

Find a general expression for $(A-2I)^n$ and apply the power series for $\log x$ in powers of $(x-2).$

Comment: is that $(A-2I)^n$?

Comment: That's what I meant, yes.

Comment: I still don't figure how that helps? $(A-2I)^n\neq 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes but only in the lower right corner so you have a log power series in the lower right corner of the result.

Comment: @ Justpassingby , your series do not converge because $||(A-2I)^n||$ tends to $\infty$ with $n$.

Comment: That is because you evaluate the full matrix. You should note that it is block diagonal; the lower right entry of the result is simply $\ln 4$ and you only need to take powers of the upper left $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: In your answer to Sucre, you speak about $(A-2I)^n$; anyway you're a big boy; do as you want.